# how to create custom tinder like swipe left or right card with animation in recyclerview without 3rd party library in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

[image: card swipe left or right]

On card appeard must be return exact position of on appeard card and disappeard card in two functions.On swipe must be return direction left or right of appeard card.ON card swiped card remove automatically

Comment: This is a huge task and I think you're unlikely to get a complete answer here. If you're against using a library, you can at least look at the source code of one to see how it's done.

Comment: You might also consider using the Internet to find existing articles on this subject. For example, for Jetpack Compose, [this article](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/modelling-dating-cards-navigation-with-appyx-ab68313d27f6) showed up last week.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MotionLayout. The concept is

- You have 3 cards: top card, middle card and bottom card
- You can use onSwipe to animate them, when the progress of motionLayout is 100% you set it to start state to keep user can swipe it infinite

There are several instruction on the web, you can check some here:
https://medium.com/bumble-tech/swipe-right-on-motion-layout-641c1452d6a5
https://rodrigomartind.medium.com/tinder-motionlayout-1cb6a7233f9f